# the ios bug is not fixed

Tags: ios, ssl

I found a link (https://www.imperialviolet.org/2014/02/22/applebug.html) which talked about some bugs in IOS and fixing those bugs. based on that link,  Apple had some bugs in the SSL process and then the bugs are fixed. the writer in that link has confirmed  that bugs are fixed on his IOS 7.0.6 (not in 7.0.4); tho, when I tried some apps on mine, the apps still had SSL vulnerability.to do this, I used mitmproxy (without configuring the certificate on my phone) and connected my phone to  mitmproxy. still, some apps easily accepted the proxy's certificate. I now wonder first, why do you think that still there is a ssl vulnerability even by fixing the errors on iOS? second, why do you think that the latest version and oldest one act the same way? seems that by updating the version, the bugs should be fixed as the developers use the components in the operating system. right?